# Query multiple tables with linked data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

OVERVIEW:

I have a rails project using a mysql DB which has data being upload from 2 sources about college students grades.

When I go to upload grades, I need to first find the "Enroll" record about what section of the course the student was enrolled in.  "Enroll" is connected to both "Student" and "Section" by belongs_to. The Student will exist in the students table, but the Section and Enroll may or may not exist.  If they do not exist I want to create them.

CURRENT CODE:

My current attempt to solve this is:

```
enrolled = Enroll.find_or_create_by(Student: student, 
    Section: {Course: course, semester: semester, year_offered: year_taken})
```

I am getting the following error:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Section.semester' in 'where clause': SELECT `enrolls`.* FROM `enrolls` WHERE `Section`.`semester` = 'Fall' AND `Section`.`year_offered` = 2012 AND `Section`.`Course_id` = 4 AND `enrolls`.`Student_id` = 11 LIMIT 1

QUESTIONS:

1) Is this the right way to go about this query?  Do I need to make it multi-step in case the Section doesn't exist?

2) Why would I be getting an unknown column error?

OTHER DETAILS:

sections = Section.where(Course: course, semester: semester, year_offered: year_taken) works fine.

Enroll belongs_to both Student and Section.

students and sections has_many enrolls
The relevant portion of the model dependency diagram is:

[image]

I am new to rails, so if there is something else you need please let me know.  Or if there is another page that explains this already, please point me there.  I found it hard to find relevant pages as I am not real familiar with the terminology when I was searching.

Comment: If you expect the `Section` table to have a `semester` column as shown in your diagram, you may need to migrate your database as Rails doesn't see it.  You can always check `db/schema.rb` to see what has been migrated.  Separately, I don't think you can create instances in separate tables with one call to `find_or_create_by`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't join to the Section table in your query.  Try this:

```
SELECT enrolls.* FROM enrolls 
INNER JOIN Section ON enrolls.belongs_to = Section.belongs_to
WHERE Section.semester = 'Fall' 
AND Section.year_offered = 2012 
AND Section.Course_id = 4 
AND enrolls.Student_id = 11 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it once for each class i.e

```
section = Section.find_or_create_by(Course: course, semester: 
  semester, year_offered: year_taken)
```

and

```
enrolled = Enroll.find_or_create_by(Student: student, 
section_id: section.id)
```